# c# ASP - call dictionary without re adding its contents each time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a website that holds a dictionary of data sets.  When a user changes pages, and I call the dictionary via its key, I always have to re add all the data sets to the dictionary. It seems kind of redundant. Is there a better way?

classA

```
public IDictionary<string, DataSet> DataDic { get; private set; }
```

classB

```
classA da = new classA();
da.DataDic.Add("Key1",".......");
da.DataDic.Add("Key2",".......");
da.DataDic.Add("Key3",".......");
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using now?  There probably is a better way, but we'll need to know the _current_ way first.

Comment: just updated with sample code

Comment: Your tagging looks wrong to me. asp classic is pre-.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's causing it:

```
ClassA da = new ClassA();
```

If you instantiate an entirely new object every time then of course you're going to have to re-populate that object every time.

Where do you get the data that you use to populate the object?  Does that data change?

If the data is static, a quick and easy thing to try is to make the field static:

```
public static IDictionary<string, DataSet> DataDic { get; set; }
```

Then you just set it once and it will retain that data.  Note that setting it is slightly different.  You wouldn't call an instance of the class, you'd call the class type itself:

```
ClassA.DataDic = new Dictionary<string, DataSet>();
ClassA.DataDic.Add("Key1",".......");
// ...
```

This may be a significant design change, depending on how this data is fetched/used/etc.  So there could be downsides that we don't see within the context of this question.

Another option is to keep it the way it is, but re-factor the populating of the data into the object's constructor:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public IDictionary<string, DataSet> DataDic { get; private set; }

    public ClassA()
    {
        DataDic = new Dictionary<string, DataSet>();
        DataDic.Add("Key1",".......");
        // ...
    }
}
```

This outwardly retains the structure of the class, just moves the populating of the data to a single place in code.  Note, however, that the data *is* still being re-populated with each new instance of the class.  So if *getting* the data in the first place is a heavy process and shouldn't happen more than once, then you might not want to go with this approach.

There are pros and cons any way you look at it.  And a lot of it has to do with factors outside the context of this question.

(Side note: Notice that I changed the case of your class in this code to begin with a capital letter.  This is an idiomatic standard in C#.  Note that the code syntax highlighter on this page didn't highlight your class names as class names.  The standard for C# is to expect classes to be capitalized.)

Answer (score 1):

Use ASP.NET caching.  Check to see if the cache key is there instead of reloading that dataset.  If it is not there, then you reloaded it from your data source

```
Cache.Insert("key", myFrequentlyAccessedData, null, 
    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx

Or...if that dataset is unique per user, that might be too much for cache, so then just add to a session variable.  Lots of ways to do this.